# AngularJs Service, File Upload, Laravel

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, laravel

I'm having trouble with an XHR Request, for some reason my server is not receiving my files:

Here is my angular service update algorithm:

```
var update = function(id, name, file) {                   

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('img', file);  

    return $http({
        method              : 'PUT',
        url                 : '/albums/' + id,
        data                : formData,
        headers             : {'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest    : angular.identity
    });

};
```

On my laravel controller I just have:

```
public function update($id) {

    return Response::json(Input::hasFile('img'));

}
```

The file is obviously there, why can't I retrieve it in my backend?

This is my request info:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8000
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/albums/1
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:13811
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryJ46EVSBw57RaVu7x
Cookie:_token=eyJpdiI6IkkzSXVmdnhubFFlVnlzSnZNWVFzVWk3ZlVKSFRDNFFlNndJWUVsVGNVU2c9IiwidmFsdWUiOiI5OG5PamUrVGZkZGx0ajZONklWajJ2OTM3MWlRd2tGZ2g5S2Jja1RhVjJ4Q1wvYk9xQTB4TlRKUWxkWmdvRm1EcHlzTGRjSEdzN2U5TWNPYWxEYVExVUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjA4NTY0ZTlmMjAyNTk3NGQxMmFhODIxMTU3NGNiYjQ4ZDA3OTgxMTA3Yzk1MmVkNmJkMGNkYjUyMmNhMzZkNzQifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjRISElnWjd3ZlwvY2k1Z1pvOERWOGxyVHlaQzEwRmlqY1FiV0tNNzZEbEs4PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYnp4UzVqOFoxMm5MMXhQdzJhVFphSkgrRGh2b2plYXhjdXpTamJ0UjVYdGdxS0puQmpPVXhObEtyb1I3XC9HQnRFdnBMWXV0MzRmWXAybGRySGRvXC9vUT09IiwibWFjIjoiMGQ1NzUyYTBjZmU3NzQ3ZDBkYjg5ZWViOGZmYzg3ZDY1ODg0N2JmNDg1NmQyNmMwZDcxMDE5NzcxZjIxM2MxMiJ9
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8000/Admin/Client
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36

Request Payload

------WebKitFormBoundaryJ46EVSBw57RaVu7x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Some Weird Album
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ46EVSBw57RaVu7x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="img"; filename="derpino.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryJ46EVSBw57RaVu7x--

Response Headers

Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 29 Oct 2014 12:47:20 GMT
Host:localhost:8000
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlQ4WlFOaG1keVhXVlA1dlluNWFZZGlMcmRQNGM3bThCRjZ6cnh4ZlorcWs9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJOZkJXNXBJQTVSTGZzWHJ4alg1SXBoN0Q2ekR6UVpnWThKQ0c4MXZOQlc1RUhNMUUraUZSTlpPYTlPTFdLQXpiYTJONkRvb29WN1djVlZkSGdaWStjQT09IiwibWFjIjoiOWI5MzEwODE2YTZlM2EzODMwZDE1YzI4YmE4M2NiYWJjMTRjMDEzOGI3YjA4NmRlMGU5NDBlZWEyMzI4MGQ3MCJ9; path=/; httponly
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.11
```

Comment: I have the exact same code on another controller an it works fine ... I don't get it

Comment: exact samecode in angular or laravel controller ?

Comment: I have another angular service, basically exactly like that, with some extra parameteres, and in my laravel controller I catch the file with Input::file(), and it works

Comment: in my other laravel controller Input::hasFile('img') return true

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML for the input, button, or whatever is initiating the update() function?

Answer (score 2):

I found the error! Apparently I can not send a file with the PUT method, I changed the method to POST and It works. In both the service and the laravel route

```
var update = function(id, name, file) {                   

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('img', file);  

    return $http({
        method              : 'PUT',
        url                 : '/albums/' + id,
        data                : formData,
        headers             : {'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest    : angular.identity
    });

};
```